# Why some parameters of AddArguments does not works?

Tags: c#, selenium

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.AddArguments("--disable-images");
options.AddArguments("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

In the end, only the user-agent parameter works. I tried to write parameters without "--", but nothing changed. I'm using chromedriver v2.32. So, how to disable chrome automation extension and images?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`AddArgument`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeOptions_AddArgument.htm) instead:

```
options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
options.AddArgument("--disable-images");
```

---

However, it is strange that you were able to set the user-agent. I suspect it has something to do with `--disable-extensions` and `--disable-images` being [Chromium Command Line Switches](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc).

Comment: The reason why useragent take effect, i think the last AddArguments overwirte the previous ones.

Comment: According to the documentation, [`AddArguments`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeOptions_AddArguments.htm) "Adds arguments to be **appended** to the Chrome.exe command line". I can't verify right now if this is true, but you may be on to something.